# Golang - What is the meaning of the seconds in CPU profiling graph?

Tags: go

For example, the data in the figure **runtime.scanobject**:

1. 13.42s
2. runtime.scanobject 9.69s(4.51%) of 18.30s(8.52%).
3. 5.33s

what is the meaning of the seconds and percent?

Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When CPU profiling is enabled, the Go program stops about 100 times per second and records a sample consisting of the program counters on the currently executing goroutine's stack.

That time and percentange is in reference to the sample.

Here is a nice reference for you to read more about it: https://blog.golang.org/profiling-go-programs